# Do we ever get to see any official S-rank missions in action (Naruto series)?

Tags: naruto

According to Narutopedia, Kakashi did 42 S-rank missions, while Minato did 39 of them. Itachi only did 1 for some reason. Many of the other jonins probably did S-rank missions too. Do we get to see or at least know about any of these missions?

Note: Naruto and Sasuke have done 0 official S-rank missions (although it's fair to say that they've done harder things in their lives).

Comment: The Zabuza mission might've been S-Ranked IF bridgebuilder was honest, though tbh Genin like Sasuke and Naruto don't do S-Rank missions

Comment: The first mission that comes to mind is the S rank mission given to Naruto (counting animals and getting their gender) during the starting of the 4th ninja war. But this was to keep Naruto occupied and to prevent him from participating in the war, so it cant be taken into account i think.

Comment: So both aren't legit S-rank missions.

Comment: Naruto did get an S rank mission ie., going to the land of lightning and recruiting animals for war ofcourse it is a trick to stall naruto.

Answer (score 4):

From the Wikia itself

> S-rank - assigned to experienced jōnin and concern state-level confidential matters. Examples are assassinating VIPs, and transporting highly classified documents. The reward for an S-rank mission is more than a million ryō.
>
> "S-rank" is also a designation given to extremely powerful missing-nin, earning them a place in their village of origin's Bingo Book. The organisation Akatsuki was stated to be comprised mostly of S-rank criminals.

Keeping this in mind we can list down plenty of missions undertaken which would've been classed as S-Rank. Thus off the top of my head the following missions should've been S-Rank even if explicitly not told so.

- Retrieval of Gaara: Clearly a S-Rank mission with Team Kakashi and
  Team Guy taking on Akatsuki members Diedera and Sasori
- The hunt for unnamed Akatsuki - Hidan and Kakuzu. Several squads of
  capable Jonin and Chunin were chosen for this S-Rank (not mentioned
  explicitly)

  > This mission led to death of a Senior Jonin Asuma.
- Hunt of Hidan and Kakuzu: Shikamaru's planned mission to kill Hidan
  and Kakuzu. Not official, but Tsunade allowed Kakashi to go along.
- The hunt for Sasuke: Nearly all the original 12 Genin, kakashi,
  Yamato etc. hunt for Sasuke. Sasuke is a S-Rank missing Nin, even if
  Leaf doesn't consider it. Again not explicit.

Edit: - Interception of Akatsuki spy may have been S-Rank, but I feel it would most probably be a A-rank. Even though they fought Orochimaru
 - The unofficial S-Rank mission given by Kakashi to Shikamaru, Naruto
   and Sakura (With Pakkun): Follow Sasuke and Stop the Sand Genins. Might've been A-Ranked. Pardon my memory. Putting in the Edit box for now.

Wiki also adds,

> These missions are exclusively assigned to highly skilled jōnin or large squads of ninja
>   This is true for almost all these missions.

Source: [Narutopedia's link on S-Rank](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/S-rank)

Comment: are these missions described explicitly as S rank or are you implying that they're S rank based on their difficulty?

Comment: @Bej If you'd read my answer I clearly say "the following missions should've been S-Rank even if explicitly not told so". The reason for this is because they are dealing with individuals who are in fact S-Rank, i.e. extremely powerful. Wiki says, "These missions are exclusively assigned to highly skilled jōnin or large squads of ninja" Which is true for majority of these missions. Except the first which only Kakashi implied was S-Rank

Comment: Again, if it's unofficial or not explicitly stated, it's technically not or not proven to be an S-rank mission. I understand that some of these missions were really difficult and were definitely S-rank level. But I really want some hard, explicit evidence that the missions were in fact S-rank, like Tsuande saying something like, "This is an S-rank mission, the reward will be high if you complete it."

Comment: If you take explicit to mean, "Hokage: I give you this S-rank mission". You'd be hard pressed to find. The examples put in this answer, pardon my hazy memory since I don't have the episodes or their transcripts handy, utilize the contextual clues available to me. The Hokage dispatching multiple teams led by Jonins? Either its a S-Rank mission or Hokage is too precautious? From the definition of "S-rank" the missions involving S-Rank Ninjas should automatically fit the bill. Is it clearly shown each and every time a S-Rank mission is handed down. No.

Comment: Also just addressing a possible "flaw" many might find is that both Neji and Guy are Jonins, so by my definition do they only do S-Rank Missions? I'd have to say, Its never Explicitly said so.

Comment: Okay, I've done some more research on this, and it lead me to this site: http://www.leafninja.com/mission.php
Apparently, there are no confirmed, but only probable S-rank missions, like some of the ones you mentioned. Still though, if you can look through the latest Naruto databooks and confirm that Naruto, Sasuke, or Shikamaru did an S-rank mission, I may believe you.